# In the project I wrote with React bootstrap, select component working wrong in the mobile screen. Options pop up on an unrelated side of the page

Tags: reactjs, select, frontend, react-bootstrap

In the project I wrote with React bootstrap, select component working wrong in the mobile screen. Options open on an unrelated side of the page. Details are in the attached photo. I tried all the positions properties but it still doesn't work.

I wrote code like this. Whats my wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGIdI.png)

Comment: Please attach you code sample

Comment: https://imgur.com/eygXu1L

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.